# Removing Found Items from a Master List<T>

Tags: c#, list, except

Okay, So I have two lists, MasterTagList and FoundTagList. The master list is set before hand with what tags should be found. The found list is made up of the tags that the reader actually finds. What I'm trying to do is determine the items in the MasterTagList that were not anywhere in the found tag list, meaning they are completely absent.

I have tried to use the Except() method, but for some reason, if the items are not in the exact order, then it says that all of the items are still missing.

I also tried code that looked something like this:

```
List<string> missing = new List<string>();
foreach (string T in MasterTagList)
{
    if (!FoundTagList.Contains(T))
    {
        missing.Add(T);
    }
}
```

I would think that the new list, missing, should show my all of the items that are in MasterTagList, but not in the FoundTagList, regardless of order. I am not an expert in C# by any manner, so I might be miss using something.

I just want to know if there is a way I can modify this code to get it to work, or if there is any other way of going about finding the missing elements, regardless of order.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Like I said, I have tried every other option I have seen suggested on here. My Except() instance looked something like this:

```
List<string> missing = MasterTagList.Except(FoundTagList).ToList;
```

Yet still, when I run the program, the missing list is always identical to the MasterTagList, although FoundTagList and MasterTagList both contain identical elements, just in different orders.

**SOLVED:**
It turns out that something must have been wrong with the way I was adding things to the lists originally; therefore, the elements in each list were not necessarily identical. I went back and modified how I was adding things to the list and now my program is working perfectly. Thank-you to all of you who had suggestions!

Comment: The Except method seems to make the most sense here. Can you show us the code you tried for that?

Comment: Are you actually working with `string`, or is that standing in for a class?

Comment: @Bobson the list is made up of several strings. Is that not what goes there? I have been assuming that meant I was treating everything like a collection of strings. I'm going to feel really bad if that was what has been wrong this whole time.

Comment: There are only two ways I can see this failing: If, for what ever reason `MasterTagList` and `FoundTagList`have values that are the same except for case (i.e. "html" vs "HTML").  Without you specifying the Comparer, I believe strings default to Ordinal.  Also, are you positive that `FoundTagList` has data in it when you pass it to Except (simple mistake, but can't rule it out)?

Comment: @Tory I am sure that they both have data. I added a button to my program so that I can view both lists just to make sure. However, I am going to go back and make sure that they are both exactly the same elements, and not any extra spaces or separators in either one.

Comment: @VarnerBeast14 - No, you were right.  Some people just try to simplify their code when they post here, and a `List<MyClass>` will behave differently than a `List<string>`.  I'm glad you got it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be pretty straightforward with the Except method

```
List<string> missing = MasterTagList.Except(FoundTagList).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

This can be verified with the following. Note that the order of the lists do not matter. It will still produce an empty list (none missing).

```
List<string> Master = new List<string>()
    { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" };

List<string> Found = new List<string>() 
    { "g", "d", "e", "h", "a", "b", "c", "f" };

List<string> missing = Master.Except(Found).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(missing.Count); //Prints 0
```

Comment: I mentioned that I have tried this method. For some reason, unless the items are in the exact order within each list, it still says that all of the items in the MasterList are missing from the found list. If there is something else I am doing wrong, please let me know, but as you have it, the missing list is still always full.

Comment: I just verified that with that written exactly as you have it, it still says all the tags are missing, even though both lists have identical elements, just in different orders.

Comment: @VarnerBeast14: I edited my answer to verify this works. Have you made sure the values in your Found list match exactly to those in the Master list? The Except method uses Equals when determining matches, which for strings are case-sensitive.

Comment: I believe I have gotten it to work now. The way I was adding things to each list, either registering things to the master list or when the tags where being added to the found list after being found, they must not have been registering as individual tags. I just could't tell based on the buttons I had added to see each list. They appeared identical to me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> missing = MasterTagList.Where(s => !FoundTagList.Contains(s)).ToList();
```

Comment: Again, when I use this, it says that the list, missing, contains all of the elements, even though both of the original lists are identical, the elements are just in different orders.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Set instead of a List. Sets only permit a single instance of a value to exist in the collection at once (according to the "Equals" method or a separate equality comparer).

Also, the "Except" method will work correctly as sets don't have any ordering.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx

Using a set will also provide an additional benefit: you don't need to check if a string already exists in the found tags list before trying to add it. If you try to add an already existing item to a set, nothing happens. The HashSet is also very efficient for this as it uses a hashtable to quickly find existing items.